# Row-wise Element Indexing in PyTorch for C++

Tags: c++, pytorch

I am using the [C++ frontend for PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/frontend.html) and am struggling with a relatively basic indexing problem.

I have an `8` by `6` Tensor such as the one below:

```
[ Variable[CUDAFloatType]{8,6} ] 
                 0           1           2           3           4           5
0       1.7107e-14  4.0448e-17  4.9708e-06  1.1664e-08  9.9999e-01  2.1857e-20
1       1.8288e-14  5.9356e-17  5.3042e-06  1.2369e-08  9.9999e-01  2.4799e-20
2       2.6828e-04  9.0390e-18  1.7517e-02  1.0529e-03  9.8116e-01  6.7854e-26
3       5.7521e-10  3.1037e-11  1.5021e-03  1.2304e-06  9.9850e-01  1.4888e-17
4       1.7811e-13  1.8383e-15  1.6733e-05  3.8466e-08  9.9998e-01  5.2815e-20
5       9.6191e-06  2.6217e-23  3.1345e-02  2.3024e-04  9.6842e-01  2.9435e-34
6       2.2653e-04  8.4642e-18  1.6085e-02  9.7405e-04  9.8271e-01  6.3059e-26
7       3.8951e-14  2.9903e-16  8.3518e-06  1.7974e-08  9.9999e-01  3.6993e-20
```

I have another Tensor with just `8` elements in it such as:

```
[ Variable[CUDALongType]{8} ] 
 0
 3
 4
 4
 4
 4
 4
 4
```

I would like to index the rows of my first tensor using the second to produce:

```
        0           
0       1.7107e-14  
1       1.2369e-08
2       9.8116e-01  
3       9.9850e-01  
4       9.9998e-01
5       9.6842e-01  
6       9.8271e-01  
7       9.9999e-01
```

I have tried a few different approaches including [`index_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.index_select) but it seems to produce an output that has the same dimensions as the input (`8x6`).

In Python I think I could index with Python's built-in indexing as discussed here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1080

Unfortunately, in C++ I can only index a Tensor with a scalar (zero-dimensional Tensor) so I don't think that approach works for me here.

How can I achieve my desired result without resorting to loops?

Comment: you want to look at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather instead of index_select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can do this in a couple different ways. One with `gather` and one with `index`. From the [PyTorch discussions](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/row-wise-element-indexing-in-pytorch-for-c/30705) where I asked the same question:

Using [`torch::gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather)

```
auto x = torch::randn({8, 6});
int64_t idx_data[8] = { 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
auto idx = x.type().toScalarType(torch::kLong).tensorFromBlob(idx_data, 8);
auto result = x.gather(1, idx.unsqueeze(1));
```

Using the C++ specific [`torch::index`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/function_namespaceat_1aa35c2bf04b75e2a7e61fcbe034acc5d4.html?highlight=index)

```
auto x = torch::randn({8, 6});
int64_t idx_data[8] = { 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
auto idx = x.type().toScalarType(torch::kLong).tensorFromBlob(idx_data, 8);
auto rows = torch::arange(0, x.size(0), torch::kLong);
auto result = x.index({rows, idx});
```