# Indexing one element per row in PyTorch matrix

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

Let `price` be a PyTorch tensor with shape `(num_days, num_products)`.

Let `purchased_product_by_day` be an integer tensor with shape `(num_days,)`, with values in `range(num_products)`.

Intuitively, `price` lists the price, for each day, of each product, and `purchased_product_by_day` are the indices of purchased products, one per day.

To obtain a tensor containing the expense per day, I can write

`price[list(range(num_days)), purchased_product_by_day]`

but this iterates over days at the Python level. I would like to obtain the same tensor on the C level.

I tried

`price[:, purchased_product_by_day]`

but that does not work, being equivalent to indexing each row by `purchased_product_by_day` for each day and stacking the results.

Is there a way to do that without iteration at the Python level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Row-wise Element Indexing in PyTorch for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507039/row-wise-element-indexing-in-pytorch-for-c), the solution in Python is

`price.gather(1, purchased_product_by_day.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze()`